# Every time I click on an element I get a file called jquery.mousewheel.min.js is created several times and freezes my browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
$(document).delegate('td','click',function(){
    var stop = 0;
    $('table > tbody > tr input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(event) {
        var stop = 1
    });

    stop = this.id  == "dontcompress" ? 1 : 0;

    if(stop == 0){
    $('[colspan="7"]').parent('tr').remove();
    $(this).parents('tr').after('<tr/>').next().append('<td id="dontcompress" colspan="7"/>').children('td').append('<div/>').css('background','#fff').children().html($('#content').html());
    }

});
```

The point of this function is to make a new row that displays some information.

This went well when I had something like this:

```
  <div id="content" style="visibility: hidden;"> something  </div>
```

But I am trying to make something more complex and started with this:

```
<div id="content" style="visibility: hidden;">

  <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                  Something:
                  </div>
              </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

After this change, whenever I press on a td, it takes a few seconds to load and spawns this 2 or 3 times:

> jquery.mousewheel.min.js?_=6346723525235

Where the numbers at the end seem to be randomly generated. I have no idea where it comes from.

I checked where these files are and they seem to come from this [site](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js?_=1495030499074).

I don't know why this is being loaded multiple times. When I stop using Bootstraps in the div content, these files are not loaded.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found how to solve it.

```
<div id="content" style="visibility: hidden;">

  <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                  Something:
                  </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just needed to add another `</div>` at the end since I opened 5 divs but closed 4.

I still don't know why or how the browser kept downloading javascript files and crashing it just because I left a div out. If someone bothers to explain the reason I will accept it as answer rather than this.